# Нужна ли запятая перед "как дань памяти"? Есть ли сравнение?

Tags: пунктуация, как

*По всей Турции установлены скульптуры Ататюрка(,) **как дань памяти** выдающемуся политику и реформатору.*
В этом случае "как дань памяти" является сравнением? Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае выражение *"как дань памяти"* **не является сравнением** и запятая перед *"как"* **не ставится**. Здесь имеется в виду, что скульптуры Ататюрка установлены **в качестве** дани памяти выдающемуся политику.